# 10.6 app rejected - can experts help me understand what to change?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

My app got rejected by apple and even after appealing and talking to them, they are unwilling to give us explicit feedback on what is wrong. They keep pointing to 10.6 guidelines and rejecting us. We feel we are doing a pretty good job abiding by it.

I would love to get some guidance on what is wrong. Screenshots of my app are below at this link in order as you would use the app.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDmv3.jpg

The app is for the Reality TV show - Dangerous Waters. The description for the app is as follows:

Follow the Dangerous Waters crew as they embark upon their quest to travel the globe on SeaDoo personal watercraft. This app allows you to get the latest location, images, videos and text updates from the DW crew. Perfect for use in between this new reality show episodes.

---

We have made sure to include all images in standard and retina format. The app has 0 bugs that apple has pointed out and also has push notification enabled.

We are really at a loss on what to do to get the app approved. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please post this question to the Apple developers forums. This is not a development-related question. No one here can solve corporate policy issues. Good luck.

Comment: hoping that other developers can give tips on whats wrong...

Comment: Post the rejection letter. Usually there's some indication why they rejected it. You can also appeal the rejection.

Comment: > Reasons for Rejection:
> *10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple,
> refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more
> work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface
> is complex or less than very good it may be rejected

Answer (score 4):

i think the reason you got rejected is because you used web view for twitter and facebook , etc .

apple does not allow that . the pretty much say web views are only used to load such local or web no WEBSITE contents .

use twitter api or facebook api  and do not add your website as in app webview , link to it through safari .

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple is rejecting you because you do not have proof indicating you have permission to display content for the Dangerous Waters TV show.

I would agree with Traveling Tech Guy and recommend you post this in the Apple developers forums where actual Apple employees can better address your issue. They would be able to better help you out. All of us here would be taking shots in the dark.

Comment: We actually confirmed with them in person that the app was being commissioned by the tv production folk.

Comment: You may need written permission that you need to provide Apple with.

Comment: We don't really think thats the case or they would have rejected as such. They have issues with the app look and feel. Hoping experienced apple devs can comment on the UI of the app after looking at screenshots.

Comment: Overall your app seems fine, but I can see you put a lot into the home function of your app (3 modules). I think those could be incorporated as separate modules themselves, as it seems that a good 50% of your app resides in the home tab item. Futheremore, if you could do anything to lessen the number of tab items, I am sure that would only help.