# flex app open in portrait in portrait instead I am forcing an app to open in landscape

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have

```
<aspectratio>landscape</aspectratio> and     <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
```

in my app.xml file, and my application supports only landscape orientation. Still apple has rejected it.

I have used air sdk 13.0.0.** and flash builder 4.7

They have givebn rejection number
10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good it may be rejected
Even my app made for iPad only

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

can you tell me why they have rejected it.

They given me rejection screenshot:

[image: app open in portrait instead of landscape]

Comment: have alook on these questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732296/10-6-app-rejected-can-experts-help-me-understand-what-to-change

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410676/phonegap-app-rejected-10-6

Answer (score 2):

You need to put AutoOrients on True. You may ask why? Your app needs to work either in landscape or portrait. Next to that it needs to work upside down or normal.

So, if it's on false and you turn your device, your app will be upside down. That is not allowed.

You can find all Review Guidlines here: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: @naveed, Does it work? If so, is it possible to accept my answer?